# footer disappear after positioning table in CSS

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have a section containing a header, a table and a footer.

```
section {
   header {
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
      right:0;
   }
   table {
      position: absolute;
      right:0;
   }
   footer {
      position: absolute:
      bottom: -300px;
   }
}
```

After I positioned my table as absolute, the footer moved to the top and got hidden from the page. So I had to force the footer into bottom -300px with absolute position. But this solution is not responsive as I shrink the height of the browser, I want the footer to be positioned after the table. I don't want a fixed position because I don't want to carry the footer as I scroll up and down the page.

Comment: upload image of your web page i need to see what you are output

Comment: Do the `header` and `table` also need to be `absolute`?

Comment: absolute element = no size. either you need to define its wrapper's height, or change that absolute positioning

Comment: ofc the footer goes up. because if you absolute position the table, then there is no content there to keep the footer down.

Comment: @MihaiT That would only be true if the footer wasn't absolute or if it didn't have top or bottom specified.

Comment: @Mr Lister The section is not positioned.